# Import-PfxCertificate password or membership issue

Tags: azure-devops, certificate, ssl-certificate, pfx, digicert

I have been working on this for days. I have a project in DevOps that I am trying to build. Part of my the build process tries to install the SSL certificate (DigiCert.pfx). This worked fine with the old certificate but we recently updated it and now it doesnt work. So I know the process is correct. Something else must be wrong.

The script being used is

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "$(CertificatePassword)" -asplaintext -force
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $(CertificateFilename) -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $password
```

When executed I get

[image: Script Output during Build]

I have updated the project file in Visual Studio with the new SSL certificate and pushed the project file and the new DigiCert.pfx file up to DevOps. I have read a bunch of articles but none that really help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, which agent do you use to run the pipeline? Microsoft-hosted or self agent? And what's the result if you run the PS script locally in develop machine, can it succeed?

Comment: Im not really sure. The Agent Specification says vs2017-win2016 so Im gonna assume Microsoft-hosted. Im taking this over from someone else so not an expert in the process.

Comment: vs2017-win2016 is microsoft-hosted agent.  And have you tried to run the PS script locally in cmd or windows powershell, same result?

Comment: So referencing this article https://github.com/dsccommunity/CertificateDsc/issues/153
I changed the certificate to TripleDES + SHA1 and it worked. Maybe a wrong version of Import-PfxCertificate. Our Agent OS in DevOps is Windows NT.

Comment: Glad to know this issue is resolved, you can add it as answer to share the useful info.